# Share Base64 photo to facebook not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, base64

I want to share the base64 image to facebook using the following code on mobile. Some of the browsers work (Chrome, Firefox,etc) but the android browser is not working.

It only show

```
"*{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}"*
```

I already spent three days but I couldn't solve it and I dont't know what wrong with this code. Anyone can help??

```
function sharephoto(){
    var imageData = "....";//base64 data mage
    var mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    try{
        var blob = dataURItoBlob(imageData,mimeType);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("access_token",accessToken);
    fd.append("source", blob);
    fd.append("message","image message");

    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ uid + '/photos?access_token=' +         accessToken, true );
    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log( xhr.responseText );
    };
    xhr.send(fd);           
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI,mime) {
    var byteString = window.atob(dataURI);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    try {
        return new Blob([ia], {type: mime});
    } catch (e) {
        var BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
        var bb = new BlobBuilder();
        bb.append(ia);
        return bb.getBlob(mime);
    }               
}
```